# columns are missing in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, theme, configuration, column

**some column are get missing before it was showing i don't know what happen now it's not showing i am attaching file please check it and help me to fix it

1. i tried cache clear
2. i tried index rebuilding but it's not work for me**

[image]

Comment: hi Ali your product  qty 100 in backend

Comment: can you share please url link

Answer (score 0):

Please update your css

```
/skin/frontend/sm_market/default/css/theme.css

.products-grid .item {
  float: left;
  height: 410px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Please change it.[image]

Comment: i just add but not working

Comment: Don't add just change this  CSS  class  `.products-grid .item`   form min-height to height properties like that  `height: 410px;`

Comment: can i send you css file if you don't mind

Comment: Yes , you can send me the file through google drive link

Comment: here is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73msxcLH0QWSUYxMVNUcjhMS1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Open this file `http://homemarket.ae/skin/frontend/sm_market/default/css/theme.css`  and find the class `.products-grid .item` and changed `min-height`  to `height` i have changed through console in your site and its work.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73msxcLH0QWQXVJNnpyemEyZlE/view?usp=sharing this is the orignal file

Comment: please clear your cache

Comment: cleared Evan not working

Comment: i already send you link can you modified and send me so i can upload please

Comment: did you changed in live, please upload it in live or just delete the var folder form root

Comment: i changed in live and uploaded

Comment: and also delete var folder its not working

Comment: i can see hear, there is still `min-height: 413px` , please check in your console

Comment: can i send you team viwer

Comment: username: 449 618 138  password: 7781

Comment: right now i have not Team Viewer

Comment: can you make a screen shot for me here is file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B73msxcLH0QWQXVJNnpyemEyZlE

Comment: in  this file on line 2030 please update `min-height` to `height`

Comment: i changed but no effect